# Session management in Hibernate (global temporary tables)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate

I've got 2 tables: `SaveBatchLocal` and `Queue`. Also, I have a procedure `SaveLocal`. `SaveLocal` removes rows from `SaveBatchLocal` to `Queue`. But I must say, that `SaveBatchLocal` is global temporary table.

If I add new rows to `SaveBatchLocal` and then call `Save` using Oracle SQL Developer, rows appear in `Queue` correctly, but not with my Spring app. As I know temorary data is visible in one session context. So, how do I have to modify my code? Does `sessionFactory` create new session everytime?

This is my code:

```
    public void add(LinkedList<SmsEntity> smsEntityList) {
            try {           
                Session session = null;
                session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                Iterator<SmsEntity> iterator = smsEntityList.iterator();            
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    session.save(iterator.next());
                }
                save(session);          
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

   public void save(Session session) {      
        Query query = session.createSQLQuery("{CALL DBManager.SaveLocal}");
        query.executeUpdate();          

    }
```

If I change my table to non-temporary, it works well.

Comment: Does Queue also hold data temporarily?

Comment: When you use sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() the session you get is scoped to thread so as long as the thread is active you'll get the same session.

Comment: do a session.flush() before calling procedure, also are you using @Transactional in your spring app ?

Comment: @user3487063, thank you a lot. BTW, do I have to flush session every time or something?

Comment: just before calling procedure should be fine,something like, session.flush(); save(session);

Comment: @user3487063, I think I could pick your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user3487063 said:

```
public void add(LinkedList<SmsEntity> smsEntityList) {
        try {

            Session session = null;         
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();      
            Iterator<SmsEntity> iterator = smsEntityList.iterator();            
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {            
                session.save(iterator.next());          
            }
            session.flush();
            save(session);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I should flush my session before `save()`

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you out

```
public void add(LinkedList<SmsEntity> smsEntityList) {
        try {           
            Session session = null;
            Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
            session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
            Iterator<SmsEntity> iterator = smsEntityList.iterator();            
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                session.save(iterator.next());
                tx.commit();
            }
            save(session);          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

 public void save(Session session) {      
    Query query = session.createSQLQuery("{CALL DBManager.SaveLocal}");
    query.executeUpdate();          

}
```

All you need is transaction to commit your changes to database.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, doesn't help. Also, SaveLocal procedure does commit.

Comment: Did you use transaction while calling session.save()?

Comment: You would have to. Look at my code it uses transaction to commit to database. If you do not commit changes, then your procedure would have no data to fill Queue.